# Javascript parse html add values of a table

Tags: javascript

my HTML code looks like this

```
    <TABLE style="" border="0" CLASS="rdThemeDataTable" id="dtWardData"
                cellspacing="0">
                <COL id="wrdActive"></COL>
                <COL id="wrdOccupied"></COL>
                <TR Row="1" CLASS="ThemeAlignCenter">
                    <TD id="wrdActive_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblactive_Row1">4</SPAN></TD>
                    <TD id="wrdOccupied_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblOccupied_Row1">4</SPAN></TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>

   <TABLE style="" border="0" CLASS="rdThemeDataTable" id="dtWardData"
                cellspacing="0">
                <COL id="wrdActive"></COL>
                <COL id="wrdOccupied"></COL>

                    <TD id="wrdActive_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblactive_Row1">6</SPAN></TD>
                    <TD id="wrdOccupied_Row1" style="width: 50px"
                        CLASS="rdThemeDataTableCell"><SPAN id="lblOccupied_Row1">2</SPAN></TD>

                </TR>
            </TABLE>

    Repeat...
```

it goes on like that for another 10 or so tables, all in the same source. editting the html is out of the question because its generated by a third party tool. all i need is add a little script at the end to add all the values of lblactive_Row1 (4 and 6 in this example)

Comment: Do you have duplicate id's at your HTML?

Comment: edited original post - all i need is add a little script at the end to add all the values of lblactive_Row1 (4 and 6 in this example)

Comment: @kamaci yes all of them are lvlactive_Row1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommanded to use duplicate ID use class instead

```
window.onload = function() {
    var data = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id == 'lblactive_Row1') {
            result += parseInt(data[i].innerHTML, 10);
        }
    }

    console.log(result);
};
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/qRNqf/11/)

Comment: getting an error:
data[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0] is undefined

Comment: never mind its working now thanks. its working but the result is not a sum of those numbers it should resturn 4+6 =10

Comment: what is it printing out? its printing out 10 on my side. use window.onload i forget to add it earlier. check the revision

Comment: i changed the console.log bit to document.write and it prints out 4. i cant edit the html at all its generated automatically

Comment: firefox. when i put document.write(result) after the IF statement closing bracket i get 004444444444

Comment: you want to put the result after close of for loop not the if

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net with your entire code? or added to the question section of this post.

Comment: sigh my mistake. checkout the new code and jsfiddle on my answer. sorry

Comment: i modified it so it grabs all the span and then check the id. which would be the ideal way.  i didn't know there are other tags within the td. let me know if this works

Comment: have to remove the javascript that aren't there because it's just throwing errors.

Comment: they work when theyre properly running inside the thrid party tool so its ok

Comment: Don't forget to specify a radix of 10 for parseInt, otherwise any values beginning with 0 will be treated as octal :)